# How can I get if a radiobutton of a group is checked?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton GroupName="a">123</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton GroupName="a">456</RadioButton>
            <RadioButton GroupName="a">789</RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False">Sumit</Button>
    </Grid>
```

As you see,here is a group of radiobutton and a sumit button.
I wanna do that,if none of radiobutton in group is checked,the sumit button is unenabled,if one of radiobutton in group is checked,the sumit button is enabled.
How can I do that?Would you like to help me?Thank you.

Comment: You have to subscibe to `Checked` event for `RadioButton`

Comment: That would involve JavaScript to fulfill your need of enabling the submit button if a radio button is checked or not. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp

Comment: Try subscribing to the CheckedEvent and set some bool 'isChecked' variable to true. Then bind the Button's enabled property to this variable

Comment: @SomeStudent this is `wpf` not `asp.net`... There is no javascript.

Comment: You have to start by reading documentation, for example: [Routed Events Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview) and [How to: Handle a Routed Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-handle-a-routed-event)

Comment: @MaciejLos Why ?  The RadioButton already has a checked event

Comment: @FCin ah, my bad.

Comment: @auburg, In a short: because WPF is not Winform. This is called good programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to handle an event handler to each of the radio buttons for when they're clicked, e.g.:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="a" Click="HandleRadioSelection">123</RadioButton>
```

And give your button a name:

```
<Button Name="SubmitForm" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False">Submit</Button>
```

Then in your code behind:

```
private void HandleRadioSelection(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    SubmitForm.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: It is a easy way.I wonder if there is another way by using xaml?

Answer (score 3):

Best way to get this done is with MVVM. You create a ViewModel-object that can be bound to your UI-elements. Then you can create a specific property that signals wether either of the buttons is checked:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="a" IsChecked="{Binding R1}">123</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="a" IsChecked="{Binding R2}">456</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="a" IsChecked="{Binding R3}">789</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
<Button Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="{Binding SubmitEnabled}">Sumit</Button>
```

Your ViewModel looks like:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool r1 = false;
    private bool r2 = false;
    private bool r3 = false;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool R1
    {
        get { return r1; }
        set { r1 = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SubmitEnabled")); }
    }

    public bool R2
    {
        get { return r2; }
        set { r2 = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SubmitEnabled")); }
    }

    public bool R3
    {
        get { return r3; }
        set { r3 = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SubmitEnabled")); }
    }

    public bool SubmitEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return R1 || R2 || R3;
        }
    }
}
```

Your Code Behind looks like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice piece of code, but I'm afraid it's just too complicated for a beginner like OP. MVVM isn't something I'd suggest to learn to somebody who, supposedly, doesn't even know binding yet.

Comment: From my point an advice here here should rather show a good and valid solution than a "quick and dirty" one.

Comment: Thanks for help,but the counts of radiobutton is variable,I can't do it like this.

Comment: Would be great to read this information in your question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is one of best paradigm to do XAML based applications. If the OP doesn't want to do follow the MVVM Approach - Triggers should do the trick.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" GroupName="a">123</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" GroupName="a">456</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton3" GroupName="a">789</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>

    <Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
               <Style.Triggers>

                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton1}" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                   </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton2}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton3}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Is there any other way that do not need to binding so many radiobutton?

Comment: Beaucase counts of radiobutton is variable,I can't do it like this.

Comment: @MelonNG You could use @Josh‘s approach then.